# Extract specific lines from multiple layers

Tags: pyqgis, line, qgis-processing, feature-extraction

In QGIS I have 16 layers (polygons) which represent the extents of shoreline erosion/recession at different time scales and scenarios into the future. Each layer contains 10 polygons. What I want to do is to extract the back line from each of the erosion polygons since this shows the extent of erosion for each year/scenario.

The most basic way of course is to just trace a line along the back of each polygon (as shown in the attached image). But that means drawing/tracing 160 lines. Does anyone know a way to extract the back line of each polygon using a processing tool or script?

I've searched the forum and tried a few tools but can't find anything suitable.

[image: erosion polygon with traced line]

Comment: What do you mean by "Back line"? How do you define that? Just the boundary (the border) of the polygon? Or the boundary of a buffer around the polygon? If so, in QGIS you can easily use the algorithm "Polygons to Lines" from menu Vector > Geometry Tools.

Comment: I'm referring to the line on the most landward side of this polygon which indicates the extent of the erosion. In the image its the red line. Yes its easy to do as you say convert the poly to a line but then i need to somehow extract that landward line from the set of lines created from the polygon

Comment: I think you have to give better definition of what exactly defines the line (in a geometric, not a geologic Sense) to get help. Right now it's as line that represents some geological fact, but how it can be determined based on the polygon remains unclear to me. The shore of a lake is always "landward".... ?

Comment: Spatially in this case its the eastern most line but sometimes the polygons are facing north so the line could be the southern most line in the polygon. i.e. it's difficult to define it geometrically because it might be different from polygon to polygon. Hence the difiiculty

Comment: I suppose you have a layer somewhere with the water bodies as well? In that case I suppose the "landward" line is the one that is the longest distance from the closest water body?